# Rails 3 dealing with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to provide user with ability to fill-in input field with special characters (i.e. **¥** and others).
User input could be saved in xml file and later fetched and rendered back to form input.

What is the best practice of saving special symbols to xml (maybe using **html entities or hexadecimal form**)?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say if you save the file in utf-8 you will have no problems.

If some controller/view has problems with encoding you have to place this in the first line:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about them and you can don't need to encode them. Let your XML library deal with that, XML supports unicode ever since, and what you call "special symbols" are just unicode characters.